# Sizeof() function of C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a=2;
if ((sizeof(a))>-1)
printf("a");
else
printf("b");
}
```

Why is the program giving output as b

When sizeof(a) = 4, which is greater than (-1)

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function. It is an operator.

Comment: Sizeof is **not a function**, it is an **operator**. That is one of the reasons why `if (sizeof a > -1 )` is valid syntax

Answer (score 4):

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (which is implementation defined unsigned integer type).

So `-1` gets converted to unsigned too. Assuming [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative integers, `(unsigned)-1` is greater than `(unsigned)4`, hence the output is `b`.

Comment: Nitpicking: Depending on the implementation `sizeof` might lead to `unsigned long`. However the issue here is the `unsigned` vs. `signed`.

Comment: @alk Yep, thanks! It is `size_t` in fact. Corrected.